# Setting names for each individual bar in group bars using Mp chart

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to set name for each bar like  S, M, W...in the image i shared. So how can i do like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class which will add **X-Axis** value in Graph

```
chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DayAxisValueFormatter(list)
```

Please pass your string array list into it.

```
class DayAxisValueFormatter(private val list: ArrayList<String>) : ValueFormatter() {

    override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        return list.getOrNull(value.toInt()) ?: value.toString()
    }
}
```

Please note this is in **Kotlin** you can have reference if you want this in **JAVA**.

Thanks

Comment: This code is setting only Group bar names, Not each Individual Bar names. I want  to Set Individual  bar name like Sun,Mon,Tue..Etc

Comment: Yes, they set individually.please post what you did.

Comment: Till now i am also able to set only Group name , not able to set individual names..So is there any method to do like that